# Chrome on Android switches audio output after rejecting an incoming call

Tags: android, google-chrome, audio, webrtc

I have an app that uses WebRTC for audio communication. When testing it on Chrome for Android I noticed that when I have bluetooth headset connected and I reject an incoming call the audio output is switched from the headset to the phone speaker. The same thing happened when I tested https://appr.tc/ and Facebook messenger.

After researching the topic all I found was this discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/DV2CRUcrtTo

Is this expected behaviour? Does anyone know the reason for it?

Comment: So apparently this is a Chrome bug (works fine in Firefox). I filed an issue report for the chromium team https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945824

Comment: Please close the question if it's unsolvable here, or fill in a solution if you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Chrome bug. It works fine in other browsers. I filled an issue report for the chromium team https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945824